# Вывести текст при отсутствии плагина.

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. 
Нужно выводить ссылку на установку плагина при отсутствии его у пользователя. Сейчас отображается вот так. 
http://pastexen.com/i/Ib2nOKAPL0.png

Это Acestream webplugin . вставляю так -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var plugin = document.getElementById("plugin");
// загрузка из торрента
plugin.playlistLoadAsync("<?php echo $video;?>", 0, 0, 0);
</script>
```

Comment: Я с html и js не очень дружу, но попробуйте сделать через noscript...

    <noscript>У вас не установлен плагин</noscript>

...или через [window.navigator.plugins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorPlugins.plugins)

Comment: Неа. Не пашет. 
И причем в есть там такой
  <embed id="plugin"  type="application/x-acestream-plugin"
где pluginspage тоже не пашет... 
А на форуме у разраба тишина...